# need Facebook API endpoint for add Authorized Ad Account IDs to app by app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot find an API for adding "Authorized Ad Account IDs" to the application.

On facebook this functional on app/{app_id}/settings/advanced/ on block "Ad accounts"
[(see on screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bePeU.png)
But what API endpoint can help add and delete adAccounts IDs from app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook support say they have not API to manage authorized ad account of application. Its manage only manually.. so if you need automation this process try use Selenium